# Arrays of strings from uproot

Tags: python, uproot

I have a tree with one branch storing a string.
When I read using `uproot.open()` and then the method `arrays()` I get the following:

```
>>> array_train['backtracked_end_process']
<ObjectArray [b'FastScintillation' b'FastScintillation' b'FastScintillation' ... b'FastScintillation' b'FastScintillation' b'FastScintillation'] at 0x7f48936e6c90>
```

I would like to use this branch to create masks, by doing things like
`array_train['backtracked_end_process'] != b'FastScintillation'`
but unfortunately this produces an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-97-a28f3706c5b5> in <module>
----> 1 array_train['backtracked_end_process'] == b'FastScintillation'

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/mixins.py in func(self, other)
     23         if _disables_array_ufunc(other):
     24             return NotImplemented
---> 25         return ufunc(self, other)
     26     func.__name__ = '__{}__'.format(name)
     27     return func

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/awkward/array/objects.py in __array_ufunc__(self, ufunc, method, *inputs, **kwargs)
    216                 contents.append(x)
    217 
--> 218         result = getattr(ufunc, method)(*contents, **kwargs)
    219 
    220         if self._util_iscomparison(ufunc):

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/awkward/array/jagged.py in __array_ufunc__(self, ufunc, method, *inputs, **kwargs)
    987                 data = self._util_toarray(inputs[i], inputs[i].dtype)
    988                 if starts.shape != data.shape:
--> 989                     raise ValueError("cannot broadcast JaggedArray of shape {0} with array of shape {1}".format(starts.shape, data.shape))
    990 
    991                 if parents is None:

ValueError: cannot broadcast JaggedArray of shape (24035,) with array of shape ()
```

Does anyone have any suggestion on how to proceed? Being able to transform it to a `numpy.chararray` would already solve the problem, but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String-handling is a weak point in uproot. It uses a custom `ObjectArray` (not even the `StringArray` in awkward-array), which generates `bytes` objects on demand. What you'd like is an array-of-strings class with `==` overloaded to mean "compare each variable-length string, broadcasting a single string to an array if necessary." Unfortunately, neither the uproot `ObjectArray` of strings nor the `StringArray` class in awkward-array do that yet.

So here's how you can do it, admittedly through an implicit Python for loop.

```py
>>> import uproot, numpy
>>> f = uproot.open("http://scikit-hep.org/uproot/examples/sample-6.10.05-zlib.root")
>>> t = f["sample"]

>>> t["str"].array()
<ObjectArray [b'hey-0' b'hey-1' b'hey-2' ... b'hey-27' b'hey-28' b'hey-29'] at 0x7fe835b54588>

>>> numpy.array(list(t["str"].array()))
array([b'hey-0', b'hey-1', b'hey-2', b'hey-3', b'hey-4', b'hey-5',
       b'hey-6', b'hey-7', b'hey-8', b'hey-9', b'hey-10', b'hey-11',
       b'hey-12', b'hey-13', b'hey-14', b'hey-15', b'hey-16', b'hey-17',
       b'hey-18', b'hey-19', b'hey-20', b'hey-21', b'hey-22', b'hey-23',
       b'hey-24', b'hey-25', b'hey-26', b'hey-27', b'hey-28', b'hey-29'],
      dtype='|S6')

>>> numpy.array(list(t["str"].array())) == b"hey-0"
array([ True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False])
```

The loop is implicit in the `list` constructor that iterates over the `ObjectArray`, turning each element into a `bytes` string. This Python list is not good for array-at-a-time operations, so we then construct a NumPy array, which is (at a cost of padding).

**Alternative, probably better:**

While writing this, I remembered that uproot's `ObjectArray` is implemented using an awkward `JaggedArray`, so the transformation above can be performed with `JaggedArray`'s `regular` method, which is probably much faster (no intermediate Python `bytes` objects, no Python for loop).

```py
>>> t["str"].array().regular()
array([b'hey-0', b'hey-1', b'hey-2', b'hey-3', b'hey-4', b'hey-5',
       b'hey-6', b'hey-7', b'hey-8', b'hey-9', b'hey-10', b'hey-11',
       b'hey-12', b'hey-13', b'hey-14', b'hey-15', b'hey-16', b'hey-17',
       b'hey-18', b'hey-19', b'hey-20', b'hey-21', b'hey-22', b'hey-23',
       b'hey-24', b'hey-25', b'hey-26', b'hey-27', b'hey-28', b'hey-29'],
      dtype=object)

>>> t["str"].array().regular() == b"hey-0"
array([ True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False])
```

(The functionality described above wasn't created intentionally, but it works because the right pieces compose in a fortuitous way.)

Comment: The second method works well and it is fast.
Do you know if something similar can be used also in case `t["str"].array()` is a `JaggedArray`? Should I transform it in a `numpy` array, perform the comparison, and then build back the `JaggedArray`?

Comment: If it's a jagged array of strings, `regular` will regularize both dimensions.